# Setar Valor Padrão Formulário HTML com PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte situação:
Tenho um exemplo simples de formulário para exibir as informações de um banco para alterar e posteriormente gravá-las novamente. Nesse caso o problema está no NOME_OPERADOR, onde eu queria que já trouxesse setado o valor que está gravado no banco, mas que oferecesse em um selct as opções para caso desejar alterar o operador responsável por determinada tarefa. Conforme o código abaixo, se eu tirar o trecho do WHILE, está trazendo certinho o operador gravado no banco, porem quando coloco o WHILE pra pegar da tabela os outros operadores, me traz todos os operadores (Como desejo), porém eu queria saber da possibilidade de em primeiro (selecionado) já viesse o operador gravado no banco referente a essa atividade. Seria mais ou menos essa a dúvida (Desculpa se ficou meio confuso). OBS: Tenho uma TABELA OPERADORES, e uma TABELA ATIVIDADES, onde fica armazenado apenas o COD do OPERADOR.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$resultado = mysql_query("select * from atividades 
                                    INNER JOIN operadores on cod_operador=codoperador_atividade
                                    where COD_ATIVIDADE = $id"); 
$dados     = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);

$reoperador = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM operadores c WHERE c.codfuncao_operador=2 order by nome_operador");

    <TRECHO DO FORM HTML>
     <select selected="selected" class="form-control" name="nome_operador" id="nome_operador" class="textBox"  value="<?php echo $dados["NOME_OPERADOR"]; ?>">  
                            <?php
                             while($l = mysql_fetch_array($reoperador)) {
                                $id     = $l["COD_OPERADOR"];
                                $nome   = $l["NOME_OPERADOR"];
                                $email  = $l["EMAIL_OPERADOR"];

                                //faz a comparação do operador selecionado com demais itens da lista             
                                $selected = ($id == $dados['COD_OPERADOR']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

                                //escreve a option
                                printf('<option value="%d" %s>NOME:%s - E-MAIL: %s</option>',$id, $selected,  $nome, $email);
                                                        }
                            mysql_close();
                            ?>

                        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deixar uma opção selecionada é necessário comparar o id do registro que será atualizado com a lista de opções(operador) e adicionar na tag `<select>` o atributo `selected="selected"`.

```
<?php
    while($l = mysql_fetch_array($reoperador)) {
        $id     = $l["COD_OPERADOR"];
        $nome   = $l["NOME_OPERADOR"];
        $email  = $l["EMAIL_OPERADOR"];

        //faz a comparação do operador selecionado com demais itens da lista             
        $selected = ($id == $dados['cod_operador']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

        //escreve a option
        printf('<option value="%d" %s>NOME:%s - E-MAIL: %s</option>',$id, $selected,  $nome, $email);
    }
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: Ajustei mas retornou os mesmo resultados, todos os OPERADORES. Em while que eu tenho utilizo o echo nessa estrutura: echo "<option value=\"$id\">COD: $id&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PROJETO: $nome&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CLIENTE: $email</option>\n";  Consigo adaptar o printf pra echo?

Comment: Quando der uma pagina em branco, adicione essas duas linhas no início do script, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` qual é o nome do campo id de `$reoperador` ? @TiagoIB

Comment: O nome do campo é COD_OPERADOR. Seria o nome na TABELA OPERADORES?

Comment: Seria assim pra incluir a tag selected? <select selected="selected" class="form-control" name="nome_operador" id="nome_operador" class="textBox"  value="<?php echo $dados["NOME_OPERADOR"]; ?>">

Comment: @TiagoIB viu a edição?

Comment: Alterei no código da pergunta de acordo com o que você sugeriu, da uma olhada. @rray

Comment: Qual edição você se refere?

Comment: Eu tinha colocado o nome da variável errado, o certo era `$dados`. @TiagoIB.

Comment: Ajustei novamente o Código da pergunta acima. Porem continua trazendo apenas os operadores. É como se não estive entendendo a tag: selected="selected". @rray

Comment: Funcionou, faltava recarregar a página anterior. @rray